# DPDK install using Meson and Ninja

Tags: ninja

I wanted to try learn things in DPDK in Debian 10 buster VM.
I have taken DPDK 20.08 as source.

I followed steps as mentioned in Compiling the DPDK Target from Source https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/build_dpdk.html#uncompress-dpdk-and-browse-sources

I have tried to follow the below steps

```
tar xJf dpdk-<version>.tar.xz
cd dpdk-<version>
meson build
cd build
ninja
ninja install
ldconfig
```

On the above when I tried

ninja

it works. Then I went for next command

If I try with

```
sudo ninja install
```

from dpdk build directory
it says sudo: ninja: command not found

If I try

```
ninja install with out sudo
```

it gets terminated with error.
It asks for sudo password then shows
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named mesonbuild
Failed Meson-install

ninja:build stopped:subcommand failed

Would appreciate your help to resolve this step.

Edit
Repeated steps with root account. Problem didn't occur. Initially it was looking in /home/vijay/.local/bin folder. Then I used from /usr/local/bin/meson

Comment: did you check you have ninja binary installed for your OS? I am marking this `needs more information` as it is missing information of OS, Kernel and Ninja version available on your platform.

Comment: Thanks Vipin for your comments. Please advise should I delete this question or marked it as solved

Comment: please update the question with the request placed in comments, So that stackoverflow can advice you the right answer. you can still use the same question,but you have to edit it.

Comment: you can approve the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error information `ninja: command not found` could be 1 of the 2 things

1. either `NINJA` utility is not installed
2. or `PATH for NINJA Binary` is incorrect

As recommended in the comment, ensure 'ninja' is installed and `you have the right path`  like `/usr/bin/` for the same.

[EDIT] @Vijay has updated it is indeed the path related issue.